# How to know from specs if one router has better range than other?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, signal-strength

I refer to various specifications of WiFi routers.

Speed `1200 Mbps, 1500Mbps, 1800Mbps.`
Does it mean that 1800Mbps has better range than 1200?

WiFi transmit power – For example below specs from a router brand.

```
WiFi Transmission Power 
CE:
<20dBm(2.4 GHz)
<23dBm(5.15 GHz~5.25 GHz)
FCC:
<30dBm(2.4 GHz & 5.15 GHz~5.825 GHz)
```

WiFi reception sensitivity –

```
11ac VHT20_MCS0:-96dBm
11n HT20_MCS0:-90dBm
```

In what way can I co-relate these above or any other specifications among various routers to conclude if one has better range than other, if so, keeping all other parameters or variables (internal/external all applicable)  constant?

Comment: Other then reviews and testing, im not sure you can. The max bandwidth is almost irrelevant and the sensitivity of the silicon and design and layouts of the antennas play a big part, as does mimo or equivalent and frequency.

Answer (score 2):

The intensity of a radio signal follows inverse square law. The further the distance, the weaker the signal.

Transmit power = how strong a signal a device can generate. 20dBm > 10dBm, consequently device generating a 20dBm signal transmits further than a device generating a 10dBm signal.

Reception sensitivity = how weak a signal a device can detect. -90dBm < -70dBm, consequently a device detecting a -90dBm signal can detect signals transmitted from a longer distance than a device detecting -70dBm signal.

This imaginary device would both transmit and detect over a longer distance in all spectrums than the one you're referring to:

```
WiFi Transmission Power 
CE:
<22dBm(2.4 GHz)
<25dBm(5.15 GHz~5.25 GHz)
FCC:
<32dBm(2.4 GHz & 5.15 GHz~5.825 GHz)

11ac VHT20_MCS0:-98dBm
11n HT20_MCS0:-92dBm
```

The "speed" or transfer rate does not indicate a better range, it refers only to the raw max throughput of the device (clarification: raw throughput between the antenna and the LAN port), in this case in megabits per second. The real-life throughput depends on the signal strength, in practice you can see this by simply the fact that a device near to the WiFi access point can transmit data faster than a device further away. In principle a device capable of 1500Mbps throughput trumps a device capable of 1400Mbps throughput.

However things in WiFi world aren't so clear-cut. The advertised transfer rates *always* refer to results of testing done in a strictly controlled lab environment. In practice due to various factors present in live production environments (including but not limited to wifi and non-wifi interference, OS/driver capabilites etc.) you will never see this kind of speeds in real life. What you can expect in an ideal environment, near to the AP, without excess interference, is at best somewhere around 2/3 of the advertised max throughput rates.